# How to Get SMS log from Twilio Webhook

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twilio, twilio-api

I am making an app in MVC to send/receive SMS using Twilio API. I am done with sending SMS functionality but I am confused to get(Inbound) SMS log sent to Twilio number from user.

There are few article but not enough for me. Please help me.

Comment: You need to read about TwiML App. TwiML app is something which you can configure on Twilio Portal. It allows you to setup public URL at which the incoming SMS data will be sent. Then you can associate you phone number with this app. The public URL is your application URL which will perform logic on the incoming SMS data from Twilio. https://twilio.radicalskills.com/library/twiml-applications.html

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I recommend this guide that was built by the Twilio documentation team on [How to Receive and Reply to SMS Messages in C#](https://www.twilio.com/docs/guides/how-to-receive-and-reply-in-csharp). It will explain what a [webhook](https://www.twilio.com/docs/guides/how-to-receive-and-reply-in-csharp#what-is-a-webhook) is, how to use [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/guides/how-to-receive-and-reply-in-csharp#what-is-twiml) and how to use that knowledge together in ASP.NET MVC to receive and respond to SMS messages.